# XenServer required for XenDesktop?

Tags: citrix, xenserver, xendesktop

I apologise if this is a very basic question, but I'm entirely new to this area and I'm finding the Citrix website very unhelpful.

Does XenServer have to be installed to allow XenDesktop to work? Where can I find some information to read about the requirements for using the XenDesktop software?

I've tested the 2x application server software and that seems much more straighforward.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes.  This is a good read and should clarify what technologies are required:
http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX121478

Bear in mind that XenDesktop v4 has only just been released so it's probably worth monitoring hxxp://community.citrix.com/blogs/tag/xendesktop for updated information too (note hxxp in the second link - I can only post one hyperlink per post at the moment!).

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on 2X ApplicationServer? Given that we would only have about 10 users it seems like a lot less hassle and much lower TCO. It only took me about 30 minutes to set up completely.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but might help anyone else searching for the topic.  As of now, XenServer is not required to run XenDesktop or XenApp (versions 7x).  XenDesktop/XenApp can be run on a Windows server.

Answer (score 0):

Not anymore, as of XenDesktop 7.x, it is multi-hypervisor. Support for ESXi, XenServer, etc. XenApp has been combined with XenDesktop as well.